# Error- Connecting Parachain to Relay Chain: Unsupported or Invalid BabeApi Version

Tags: substrate-node-template, parachain, relay-chain

I have already run a `relay chain` on two ports, but when I try to connect my `parachain` to the `relay chain`, I encounter the following error. I have attached a screenshot of the error to this message.

[image]

> **I am getting this error message**

```rs
Error message:
2023-06-07 13:07:11 Parachain Collator Template    
2023-06-07 13:07:11 ✌️ Version 0.1.0-677a1a238a9    
2023-06-07 13:07:11 ❤️ By Anonymous, 2020-2023    
2023-06-07 13:07:11  Chain specification: Local Testnet    
2023-06-07 13:07:11  Node name: Bob    
2023-06-07 13:07:11  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-06-07 13:07:11  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/parachain/bob/chains/local_testnet/db/full    
2023-06-07 13:07:11 ⛓ Native runtime: template-parachain-1 (template-parachain-0.tx1.au1)    
2023-06-07 13:07:13 Parachain ID: Id(1000)    
2023-06-07 13:07:13 Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ    
2023-06-07 13:07:13 Parachain genesis state: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004f3fb323d861297b5ffdafa44cae2b676644e242cc24ad1ca45eb430ad191c2803170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400    
2023-06-07 13:07:13 Is collating: yes    
Error: Service(Other("Polkadot service error: Failed to get runtime version: Unsupported or invalid BabeApi version"))
```

I followed this link:

```
[https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/]
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a mistake in your parachain command i know you were follow a doc but you can try once my command and let me know is it works or not..

```
**  ./target/release/parachain-template-node --alice --collator
--force-authoring --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json --base-path /data/para1 --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 -- --execution wasm --chain
 ../polkadot/customSpecRaw.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9945 --bootnodes
 /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWD9puWKTqjajFmsiBj7it9iHLoM2sdWKztrg81CRkHZ3a**
```

You can change path according to your path and the last address is local identity of relay chain which is `12D3KooWD9puWKTqjajFmsiBj7it9iHLoM2sdWKztrg81CRkHZ3a`you can add your relay chain local identity and ws-port 9945 is relay chain port you can edit command according to your ws-port